# Python Gensim Dictionary

Tags: python, gensim

This is my input (sample*)

```
data = ["['human', 'interface', 'computer']",
 "['survey', 'user', 'computer', 'system', 'response', 'time']",
 "['eps', 'user', 'interface', 'system']",
 "['system', 'human', 'system', 'eps']",
 "['user', 'response', 'time']",
 "['trees']"]
```

And I have tried implementing

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(text_data)

But this is the error I get,

TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string

Please help if you see why that wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

This error means that each "sentence" fed into doc2bow is expected to be an array of strings ("tokens"), whereas you are providing each "sentence" as a string:

```py
# Your input sentences:
data = [
    "['human', 'interface', 'computer']",
    "['survey', 'user', 'computer', 'system', 'response', 'time']",
    "['eps', 'user', 'interface', 'system']",
    "['system', 'human', 'system', 'eps']",
    "['user', 'response', 'time']",
    "['trees']"]

# Expected input sentences:
data = [
    ['human', 'interface', 'computer'],
    ['survey', 'user', 'computer', 'system', 'response', 'time'],
    ['eps', 'user', 'interface', 'system'],
    ['system', 'human', 'system', 'eps'],
    ['user', 'response', 'time'],
    ['trees']]
```